# Is there any way to add the windows ribbon shortcuts to Excel 2016 on Mac without using a Virtual Machine

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

Perhaps you could use Wine, or maybe someone has created a modified version of Excel?

Answer (score 2):

No. The Ribbon is coded into the Office software and cannot simply be added by plugin or some software modification.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with music2myear, you can't modify or change the ribbon of Office like that. the only thing you can do is [Customize the ribbon in Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31)